# how can I access to new function via getcomponent?

Tags: c#, unity

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using AssemblyCSharp.portal.www.com;

    public class Game5_Player: MonoBehaviour
    {
//string Logo;
        void Start ()
        {
            func webservice = new func ();//I should use new func(); so how should I use public func?
            //Logo= webservice.getCompanyLogo ();//this work correctly.I can get component Logo In another script but I want know how can I getcomponent my function.
        }
    }
```

why have I error when use Getcomponent In below?
other script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using AssemblyCSharp.portal.www.com;

public class MasterRange : MonoBehaviour {
        string Logo;
        void Start () {
        Game5_Player game5_Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Game5_Player> ();
            Logo = game5_Player.webservice.getCompanyLogo;
        }
    }
```

error:

```
 Assets/MasterRange.cs(21,34): error CS0103: The name `webservice' does not exist in the current context
```

---

Is there any way to have a public new function?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using AssemblyCSharp.portal.www.com;

public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour {
string Logo;

public func webservice = new func();

void Start ()
{
    webservice();
    Logo = webservice.getCompanyLogo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, `webservice` is declared as a local variable within the scope of the `Game5_Player`'s `Start()` method:

```
public class Game5_Player: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        func webservice = new func ();
    }
}
```

This means that only code inside the `Start()` method can access `webservice`, and when `Start()` returns, `webservice` will generally be cleaned up/garbage collected, unless you've stored a reference to it elsewhere.

What you want to do is declare `webservice` in a longer-lived scope, like as a member variable:

```
public func webservice;  // Declared as a member variable.

void Start ()
{
    webservice = new func (); // Initialized in Start, Awake, or OnEnable.
}
```

Now anything with access to your `Game5_Player` instance can read OR overwrite `webservice`.

If you want to exert more control over how the variable can be used, you can do something like...

```
public func webservice { get; private set; }
```

This uses an auto-implemented property to ensure outside code can only get the value of `webservice`, but can't set it.

You could also declare your own getter function to initialize `webservice` the first time it's requested, something like...

```
private func _webservice; // Private backing member variable.
public func webservice    // Public property.
{
    get
    {
        if(_webservice == null)
           _webservice = new func(); // Initialize.

        return _webservice;
    }    
}

void Start()
{
     // We can just use webservice directly,
     // knowing it will be initialized first if necessary.
     logo = webservice.getCompanyLogo();
}
```

This way even if another script tries to read `webservice` before `Game5_Player` has run its `Start()` method, it will get an initialized version back.

Answer (score 0):

thank you DMGregory I can solve my problem:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using AssemblyCSharp.portal.www.com;

public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour {
    private crm1 _webservice; // Private backing member variable.
    public crm1 webservice    // Public property.
    {
        get
        {
            if(_webservice == null)
                _webservice = new crm1(); // Initialize.

            return _webservice;
        }    
    }
}
```

other script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using AssemblyCSharp.portal.www.com;

public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour {
    public string Logo;

    void Start(){
        ScriptA scripta = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<ScriptA> ();
        Logo = scripta.webservice.getCompanyLogo();
    }
}
```